# Merging these two queries

Tags: mysql, sql, merge

I was listing this two queriess as separate, but now I need the results in the same list.

Right now I have it 'fixed' by ordering the items by id using javascript. But it would be great to get this data merged from the server so I would be able to page the results..

DATABASE SCHEMA

Table Friends:

[image]

Table helps

[image]

Query A (returns results from the **current user**)

```
   $sql = 'SELECT * FROM helps WHERE id_user ='.$value;
```

Query B (returns results from the **current user's friends**)

```
$sql = 'SELECT
    h.*,
    f.* 
    FROM (
            SELECT
                     id  AS friendsId,
                     CASE followerid WHEN '.$value.' THEN followingid ELSE followerid END AS friend_id
                        FROM friends
                        WHERE acepted = 1
                        AND (followerid  = '.$value.' OR followingid = '.$value.')
                    ) AS f
                        INNER JOIN helps AS h ON h.id_user = f.friend_id
                        ORDER BY h.id DESC';
```

Is there a way to merge these queries? I honestly have no clue how to.

-EDIT-

Considering union, but I don't know how to handle the order by thing..

```
$sql = '(SELECT * FROM helps WHERE id_user = '.$value.')
                    UNION
                    (SELECT
                                h.*,
                                f.* 
                            FROM (
                                SELECT
                                    id  AS friendsId,
                                    CASE followerid WHEN '.$value.' THEN followingid ELSE followerid END AS friend_id
                                FROM friends
                                WHERE acepted = 1
                                AND (followerid  = '.$value.' OR followingid = '.$value.')
                            ) AS f
                                INNER JOIN helps AS h ON h.id_user = f.friend_id
                                ORDER BY h.id DESC)';
```

As you can see in the second query helps table has been renamed to h. How can I do the same in the first? (both queries return the data in the same format)

Comment: please define "merge" in this context

Comment: much better if you can include the schema of your tables. maybe there are better ways than using `UNION`.

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet try my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic rules of `UNION` are

- the number of columns returned by each query must be equal and
- the data types must match with one another.

As you can see, i haven't modified the queries you formulated. Only that I added a *Virtual Column* for each query. This column will be used for ordering all the records. The queries were wrap by another `select statment` so the virtual column won't show on the result list but it will be the basis for ordering the records. The result of the query below contains the records of the user at the top most (*because of `ORDER BY OrderBy ASC`*) and the followed by the records of the user's friends sorted by friend's ID. If any clarification you want, please do inform me. One more thing, I removed `f.*` in your second query because it is not necessary and can cause error on your syntax due to column (*number*) mismatched.

```
SELECT  ID, Title, Content, ID_User, ID_Group, 
        ID_Type, ID_Loc, Avatar, Attached, Fecha, Likes, 
        Lan, NeedsCount, RecivedCount
FROM
    (
        SELECT *, 1 as OrderBy           -- first query you formulated
        FROM helps 
        WHERE id_user = '.$value.'
        UNION
        SELECT  h.*, 2 as OrderBy        -- second query you formulated
        FROM    (
                    SELECT  id  AS friendsId,
                            CASE followerid 
                                WHEN '.$value.' THEN followingid 
                                ELSE followerid 
                            END AS friend_id
                    FROM    friends
                    WHERE   acepted = 1 AND 
                            (followerid  = '.$value.' OR followingid = '.$value.')
                ) AS f
                    INNER JOIN helps AS h 
                        ON h.id_user = f.friend_id
    ) x
ORDER BY OrderBy ASC, ID DESC
```

Comment: hi there but i dont want to rename the fields, same function will read the results...

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet actually there are no fields that were renamed on the query :D

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3     very hard to tell...

Comment: renamed to fields real name and works! SELECT  id, title, content, id_user, id_group, 
           id_type, id_loc, avatar, attached, fecha, likes, 
           lan, needsCount, recivedCount
     FROM

Comment: yes! thats actually what i was saying in my first comment. renamed fields. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

To merge the result of these two queries and order records you need to use [UNION ALL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html) with `GROUP BY`. Try this query:

```
SELECT h.id AS id, h.title, h.content, id_user, h.id_group,
       h.id_type, h.id_lic, h.avatar, h.attached, h.attached,
       h.fetcha, h.likes, h.lan, h.needsCount, h.receivedCount,
       MAX(h.fid) AS fid, MAX(h.friend_id) AS friend_id
FROM (   
      SELECT h.id AS id, h.title, h.content, id_user, h.id_group,
             h.id_type, h.id_lic, h.avatar, h.attached, h.attached,
             h.fetcha, h.likes, h.lan, h.needsCount, h.receivedCount,
             0 AS fid, 0 AS friend_id
      FROM helps h
      WHERE h.id_user ='.$value.'

      UNION ALL

      SELECT h.id, h.title, h.content, id_user, h.id_group,
             h.id_type, h.id_lic, h.avatar, h.attached, h.attached,
             h.fetcha, h.likes, h.lan, h.needsCount, h.receivedCount,
             f.id AS fid, f.friend_id
      FROM (
             SELECT id  AS friendsId,
                    CASE followerid WHEN '.$value.' THEN followingid
                                    ELSE followerid
                    END AS friend_id
             FROM friends
             WHERE acepted = 1
                   AND (followerid  = '.$value.' OR followingid = '.$value.')
            ) AS f
            INNER JOIN helps AS h
                ON h.id_user = f.friend_id
     ) h
GROUP BY h.id
ORDER BY h.id DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks I will test and let you know

Comment: Unknown column 'h' in 'field list'

Comment: Unknown column 'f.id' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0):

Try the `UNION` operator if the resultset for both the queries are similar

Comment: well it does not work if the selected columns are different. For syntax please look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Comment: i could but i need to rename helps as h in the first table, can you help? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do a UNION just as Omesh described, and then to handle the ordering, do this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    ....Omesh's code....
) T
ORDER BY T.id DESC
```

Comment: Same problem... Unknown column 'h' in 'field list'